# Как передать возвращенное значение в виджет Text?

Tags: flutter

```
class MainContainer extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Container(
      child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: ButtonTheme(
          minWidth: 220.0,
          height: 30.0,
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _getingResult(context);
            },
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text(
              'second screen',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Text('Don\'t result') //...
    ],
  ));
}

void _getingResult(BuildContext context) async {
  final result = await Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));
  //...
  }
}
```

В SecondScreen() просто передаю String переменную назад в MainContainer(), эту переменную хочу вывести в виджет Text('Don\'t result'), но не знаю как делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не помню точно для чего это нужно было, но поможет `FutureBuilder`